# Fortran passing array slices as arguments

Tags: arrays, fortran, slice

I have a variable number of matrices of different sizes. Therefore I store them in a big enough 3D array. But I have a subroutine that takes such matrix as argument. I thought it is possible to pass matrix like slice, but it seems to lead to segfault.

```
 call mysubroutine(A(:N,:M,i),N)
```

Here N, M are the sizes of i-th matrix. Is it possible to pass slices of arrays?

Edit:

Forgot, N is passed also, and a subroutine header

```
subroutine mysubroutine(A,N)
dimension A(N,*)
...
```

Comment: It is possible, but a temporary array may be created. Which compiler do you use? Likely the temporary is put on the stack and a Stack Overflow happens. You also should show the header of the `subroutine`. A fix could be to use assumed shape arguments in the subroutine.

Comment: @VladimirF thank you, that seems to be correct, as segfault happens if I write matrix member with big index. I use gfortran.
Added subroutine header.

Comment: *I have a variable number of matrices of different sizes. Therefore I store them in a big enough 3D array.*  Which might be the root of the problem; perhaps storing them as individual arrays would be a better approach in your case.

Comment: gfortran should not be too susceptible to stack overfows in this case unless you request `-fstack-arrays` yourself. Enable also error checking (`-g -fbacktrace -fcheck=all -Wall`) and try to use `dimension A(:,:)` (explicit interface required! - best acheived by using modules).

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark I agree that it is not very elegant approach, but I can't store them individually because their number is not fixed. Perhaps, array of pointers to array will work.

Comment: *because their number is not fixed*  might be a case for allocatable arrays.  Or pointers as you say though I find myself using them much less now that we can have allocatable.

Comment: Or possibly an allocatable array of derived types, depending on exactly what is being done (really a version of what Mark said, but maybe best to spell it out). Pointers are rarely the way to go.